# Forcing a WCF service to communicate with clients infinitely

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service, and two WPF applications which acts as clients for service. I need the communication between clients and service to be infinite, even when those are not interacting(i.e. client is idle). Right now my service drops the connection after some time.

I have tried increasing reciveTimeout and sendTimeout (even tried setting it to "infinite") on my bindings but it didn't worked. If anyone can put some light on how different timeouts are used and what values i need to set for my case.

Any help will be of great value.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What is your hosting environment? Why do you need client to be connected when it is idle? It is waste of resources isn't it?

Comment: Before you actually call the WCF methods, use a method to connect to the server. What this method actually do is, if the connection is live, dont bother just return, otherwise connect to the service.

Comment: Kaf, I am hosting the service inside a WPF application. I need these apps to be able to be communicate at any time, and these apps keeps running for hours and hours.

Comment: Lary : Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the timeout defaults you can make a Keep Alive background thread in WPF that will ping your WCF service every minute.

Comment: Actually I have tried this approach earlier I am trying to ping the service every 5 minutes, but that didn't worked, it drops the connection after around 1 hour.